# android how can I export signed apk file programitically

Tags: android, export, apk, sign

I want to create an application creator. It means that I want user to create its own application using my application and export signed apk file on its device.
Is this possible in android?

If it is possible then please help me so that I can implement it.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible but it requires **Rooted Device**.

Now you need to create script (android commands) for

- compiling
- packaging
- creating key-store
- signing to key-store into release mode

We are allowed to do above all things using command. Try to follow it one by one and you can generate **.apk** file.

Comment: Greate,Can you give me some link to do that?

Comment: @john yeah sure try from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline), [here](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/tools/building/building-cmdline.html), [here](https://www.built.io/blog/building-android-applications-apk-from-the-command-line)  or [here](https://blog.fossasia.org/getting-signed-release-apks-from-the-command-line/). and please mark answer as true if you have got it.